# Adding More Column in Customer OSCommerce Admin Page

Tags: admin, oscommerce

i'm a little bit struggling regarding how can i add more column in the costumer tabs in the admin page OSCommerce. As we can i only can display 8 customer in one page. How can i increase it ?

[image]

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say for sure without seeing your catalog/admin/customers.php file...  Is the following code in your customers.php file?

```
$customers_split = new splitPageResults($HTTP_GET_VARS['page'], MAX_DISPLAY_SEARCH_RESULTS, $customers_query_raw, $customers_query_numrows);
```

If so, then check the value of MAX_DISPLAY_SEARCH_RESULTS in your database.  MAX_DISPLAY_SEARCH_RESULTS is in the 'configuration" table.  If it is set to 8 then adjust it to the number of customer rows you prefer to see in the customers table.

Keep in mind that MAX_DISPLAY_SEARCH_RESULTS is used elsewhere and whatever value you adjust it too will be used everywhere MAX_DISPLAY_SEARCH_RESULTS is used.

Comment: Thank you dude !! i also found this solution is working http://forums.oscommerce.com/topic/336359-how-to-change-page-layout-to-show-more-products/

Comment: @Shan Markus Excellent. Glad to hear it worked out.  Good call on using admin >> max values >> search results to adjust the value rather than phpmyadmin.